# Increasing the font size of a webview conflict with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i have a UIWebView inside a UIScrollView. 
I am using this code to increase the font size of the UIWebView:

```
int fontSize = 150;
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc]      initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",     fontSize];
[LabelNewsContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
NSString *size = [LabelNewContent stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return      Math.max( \
document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, \
document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight, \
document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight  \
);"];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.contentSize.width, [size floatValue]);
```

The font increase happens without any errors but only half of the text inside the UIWebView is visible.

Comment: Well, apart from the UIWebView, i have a UIimageView and a label, i add all of them as the subviews of the UIScrollView so that they can all scroll up and down together. thats why!

Comment: WebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; can u please try this...

Comment: Where should i insert WebView.scalesPageToFit = YES ?

Comment: just below the webview object where you initialize your webview....u got the webview r8??

Comment: i did put it there and this is what happened! [link](http://i.imgur.com/3WMmBjm.png)

Comment: so is it solved or not???i cant see any text out of uiwebview

Comment: its not out of the webview but the font becomes so small that the webview fits only one page. im supposed to increase the font size!